# Data Modeling where super class isn't clear

Tags: oop, data-modeling

I am trying to use OOP to model the relationship between classes where either can be OF the other.

For example: In a hierarchical business, you might have the Corporation -> Has -> Businesses -> Has -> Departments

Simple enough. But, what if the a different business acquires this corporation. Then the corporation will be part of the business rather then the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an interface or the most common properties for the base class. For example:

```
public abstract class BusinessUnit {
     protected ArrayList<BusinessUnit> businessUnits;
}
```

And in the classes:

```
public class Corporation extends BusinessUnit { }

public class Business extends BusinessUnit { }
```

Of course you'll have to handle it differently inside the classes according to the BusinessUnit type.